# Email masking with CFX_ActiveMail

Tags: coldfusion

One of legacy application is using  ActivMail for mails. I reckon it could be due to because earlier versions (prior to CF8) were slow in sending emails. Anybody has any idea can I mask emails (sender's name should appear instead of email address) with this custom CFX tag(CFX_ActiveMail)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Adding some of the code snippets you have tried so far will help out the experts to analyse the problem.

Comment: Does the tag come with any documentation? I can't see much about it on Google, and nothing helpful (which I imagine is the same conclusion you arrived at). Which version of ColdFusion are you on? If - as you hint at - you're on a more recent version than had issues with CFMAIL, it might perhaps be worthwhile just switching back to using CFMAIL, rather than relying on long-dead third-party stuff. It seems a bit risky to me.